# JavaScript Keyboard Event Not Firing

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

For some very odd reason when you press keys in the order of forward, spacebar, and left. Left does not fire and returns spacebar instead. Any other combination of three keys works perfectly fine, but not that one. Any clues as to why?

```
var Ctrl = {
    init: function() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown, true);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyUp, true);
    },

    keyDown: function(event) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);

        switch(event.keyCode) {
            case 37: // Left
                Ctrl.left = true;
                break;
            case 39: // Right
                Ctrl.right = true;
                break;
            case 38: // up
                Ctrl.up = true;
                break;
            case 40: // down
                Ctrl.down = true;
                break;
            case 32:
                Ctrl.space = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    },

    keyUp: function(event) {

        switch(event.keyCode) {
            case 37: // Left
                Ctrl.left = false;
                break;
            case 39: // Right
                Ctrl.right = false;
                break;
            case 38:
                Ctrl.up = false;
                break;
            case 40:
                Ctrl.down = false;
                break;
            case 32:
                Ctrl.space = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible that the problem may be elsewhere? For example, where do you set `Ctrl.space` to `false` after you've read it?

Comment: Checked the code and nothing else is wrong. The event itself refuses to return it, so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on model of your keyboard. Some keyboards doesn't work with some key combinations. It's normal.

Comment: Yes not all keyboards are the same, you can possible make sure that your regional settings and keyboard layout, is set to the correct country you are in.

Comment: I would guess that there is a bulletproof way to detect keyboard input? Maybe not?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of your keys is activating an unwanted default behavior. You can try to add `event.preventDefault();` to your event bindings.

[check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/evHHF/)

Comment: Gave that a try and it didn't seem to do anything. Good guess though.